# Python open() Mac OS X Komodo Edit

Tags: python, macos, komodoedit

I started now to learn Python, so my question is kinda stupid

I have this piece of code

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
# encoding: utf-8

fh = open("lines.txt")

for lines in readlines():
    print(lines)
```

the text file lines.txt exits and it is at the same directory of my page, I using Komodo Edit, when I run the file, I get this error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Jeff/Sites/PythonLearning/forloop.py", line 4, in <module>
    fh = open("lines.txt")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lines.txt'
```

Funny thing, if i open this file in IDLE, it works nicely, as well if I open in Mac os X terminal!

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: +1 for using Komodo, my favorite editor for Python!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error because by default when you run a script in Komodo Edit it does not run it from the directory the script is saved in (unlike when you run normally from the command terminal).

To fix this - when you select the '`Run Command`' option in Komodo Edit - Click '`More`' to bring down a further options list and then in the '`Start In`' field enter `%D`. This tells Komodo to run the script from the directory it is in and should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`print os.getcwd()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getcwd) to find out what's your working directory. It'd probably not what you expect.

Comment: I get this NameError: name 'os' is not defined

Comment: @Jeff Dias: Please read a tutorial.  You need to import `os`.